# A href and click events ？ concurrently perform？

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Vue

Goal: Code An array of loops，A link anchors ‘href’

```
<a class="mui-control-item"
    v-for="(item, index) in dai" v-on:click ="abc(item)" :href="'#item'+(index+1)+ 'mobile'"
    :key="index"
    :class="{'mui-active':!index}">
    <!-- <p  style="z-index: 99;"> -->
    {{item.value}}
    <!-- </p> -->
</a>
```

Method: click Acquired parameters

```
abc(item, index) {
    // location.href = '#item' + (index + 1) + 'mobile'
    this.oIndex = item
    console.log(oIndex, 'aa')
}
```

I want to let it be ‘click‘ and ‘href’ simultaneous execution or first one after one，I don't need to click it two times

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not "gimme what I want" kind of service. [Learn how to ask question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If the href directs to another page then your  script will not be executed.

Comment: I'm a beginner.My English is not good.I want to get the parameters by clicking and pass it to the subpages using V-IF

Comment: please reformulate your question.

also, as @jeff pointed out, either you run the function or navigate away. pick one.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
<div class="mui-control-item" v-for="(item, index) in dai" @click="abc(item, index)" :key="index" :class="{'mui-active': !index}">
```

```
abc(item, index) {
    this.oIndex = index;
    console.log(index, 'aa');
    this.$router.push('item/' + (index + 1) + '/mobile');
}
```